# BQ Streaming Upsert / Update is there a plan for this?

Tags: google-bigquery

Im curious as to whether on the roadmap there is planned a streaming update, or better still 'upsert', into BQ to complement streaming inserts?  Upsert a document based on key would open up a world for use cases where insert / append only is not the best option.

e.g importent idempotent sinks for Spark Structure Streaming, OutputMode.Update for windowing functions in-line with Spark semantics, just general idempotency?

On DML updates/deletes, is there plans to increase the quotason this for jobs? Seems quite small at 96 per table per day?

Thoughts?

Cheers!

Comment: I recommend to open an issue in https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/ and officially ask for the features if you need them for your workflow.

Comment: cool Ive done that thanks